# Apple's point of view on UISplitViewController?

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I am trying to have an application that occasionally uses a **UISplitViewController** for some editing and other operations. I figured out that I am not allowed to push/modal **SplitViewController** on a **UINavigationController** by Apple.

So for solving this problem, I created my SplitView and switched it with my **Window** View in the AppDelegate. Well, it all works and eveything, now my question is:

**Will Apple approve this? If not, what workaround is accepted?**

The transition is not really smooth, basically it ***suddenly*** changes the view without any animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

Slightly longer answer: There's no real problem with that, and I don't think apple will have a problem with it, just be careful with your view controller hierarchy. It's a workaround so be careful with how you go back to the original nav controller and how you pass data to it.